# Error when writing copy constructor for class with static array

Tags: c++

I am getting the error "array used as initializer" when trying to write copy constructor for the below class. Kindly help me with this issue! :)

Code :

```
class A
{
    int arr[10];

public:
    A() : arr{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100} {}
    A(int n) : arr{n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n} {}
    A(const A &ref) : arr(ref.arr) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2(a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
testing.cpp: In copy constructor ‘A::A(const A&)’:
testing.cpp:8:34: error: array used as initializer
    8 |     A(const A &ref) : arr(ref.arr) {}
      |                                  ^
```

Comment: Arrays are not copyable. Use `std::array` instead; you won't even need to write a copy constructor explicitly then, the implicitly-defined one would work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not copyable", please?? What do I do if I do not want to use std::array for this code ??

Comment: You can copy the array element by element, with a loop or `std::copy` call.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but since the array can be trivially copied and you don't have any other members that require explicit allocation or special handling, you can rely on the default copy constructor to do the right thing instead of explicitly defining one yourself.

Comment: Array element by element copying is basically this "A(const A &ref) : arr{ref.arr[0],ref.arr[1],ref.arr[2],ref.arr[3],ref.arr[4],ref.arr[5],ref.arr[6],ref.arr[7],ref.arr[8],ref.arr[9] } {}", correct??

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary constructor. Member automatically would be copied.

```
//    A(const A &ref) : arr(ref.arr) {}
```